# Will the Nikkor 55-300mm/f4.5-5.6 lens work with Nikon D5200?

Tags: lens, nikon

I need to know if Nikkor 55 mm - 300 mm f/4.5 - 5.6 Super Telephoto Zoom Lens will work with my Nikon D5200 camera. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are referring to the [Nikon AF-S DX NIKKOR
55-300mm f/4.5-5.6G ED VR](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Camera-Lenses/2197/AF-S-DX-NIKKOR-55-300mm-f%252F4.5-5.6G-ED-VR.html) - Yes of course it will work. The Nikon D5200 is a DX format camera with an F-Mount, and this is a DX format F-Mount lens. The D5200 does not have an autofocus motor built into it, but any lens that is "AF-S" has it built into the lens. So this lens will autofocus on the D5200.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

It's an AF-S which has auto-focus built into the lens. Moreover, it's a DX lens which  was built for your DX Nikon D5200. It'll work.

Answer (score 1):

The Nikkor 55-300mm f/4.5-5.6G DX lens was a bit of a surprise when it was announced, as Nikon already had two very good telephoto zooms that appealed to DX body users (55-200mm DX and 70-300mm VR). Why Nikon was revisiting the low-cost telephoto space before filling out other DX options had a lot of Nikon users puzzled. Still, with two low-cost cameras (D3100, D5100) in the lineup, having low-cost lenses for them seems like the right thing to me. The question at hand is whether this was the right addition to the low cost lineup.

Read More : http://webcamerawebcamera.com/detail.php?&id_detail=35

Comment: This is interesting background, but actually, the "question at hand" is simply whether this lens will work on a D5200. More info is great, but please do at least answer the question -- this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It will.
DX means the same format your camera is made for.
AF-s means the lens has an auto focus motor in it. as your camera does not have a built-in auto focus system, this lens will work perfectly.

However if you are too buried with the lens abbreviations, you can check out this link: 
http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/compatibility-lens.htm
I found it pretty informative.